# what is the work of below code?

Tags: wpf

i can not understand this line `{helpers:CommandBinding AddCommand}` 
   the code is here :

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="E" Command="{helpers:CommandBinding AddCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

explain every markup in the above code:
if there is other option available then explain me .

Comment: the code is here :<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="E" Command="{helpers:CommandBinding AddCommand}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>

Comment: You need to put the code in the question rather than as a comment.

Comment: Read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a custom [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx), which presumably returns a command. Ask whoever wrote it or if it's part of some framework see the docs...

Comment: can u explain this line working plz plz:<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="E" Command="{helpers:CommandBinding AddCommand}"/>

Comment: @user1334247: Read the damn [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx).